# Python convert data based on data type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I created a Pandas Series like this:

```
txt = pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', ""])

print(txt)
```

Result:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5     
dtype: object
```

Find out type of each item and gives me 'str' as result.

```
type(txt[0])
type(txt[5])
```

Try to convert each item into 'int' type with .astype() but failed.

```
txt.astype('int')

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Try to convert each item into 'int' type with a self-defined function but got error.

```
txt.apply(lambda num: int(num))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Someone please advise me how to do data type conversion in this case. My plan is to create 2 pandas Series and perform maths operation on both Series.

Comment: hint: you cannot convert an empty `str` to type `int`

Comment: Use `pd.to_numeric(txt , errors='coerce').astype('Int64')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `to_numeric`:

```
import pandas as pd

txt = pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', ""])
print(txt)
print(txt.dtypes)
txt_int = pd.to_numeric(txt, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
print(txt_int)
print(txt_int.dtypes)
```

OUTPUT:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5     
dtype: object
object
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5    <NA>
dtype: Int64
Int64
```